# Order Relation property

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $ S = \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Z} $, consider the application:
$$\mathcal{f}: (x,y) \in S \rightarrow x^2 +y^2 \in \mathbb{N}$$
and his Equivalence nucleus be $\mathcal{R}$
Now we define $\sigma$ as a order relation in S:
$$\forall (x,y),(z,t)\in S \space \space (x,y)\sigma(z,t)\longleftrightarrow ((x,y)=(z,t)\vee x^2+y^2<z^2+t^2)$$
How do i check if $\sigma$ is total order? And last question, is it correct to say those statements:

- the the minimum element is (0,0) because it is in relation with everything in S
- the maximum doesn't exist because $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ go to infinity
- the minimal elements are all couples $(0, y)$ with $y>0$ because they are the minimum of their respective class of equivalence
- the maximal elements don't exists for the same reason of the maximum.

Comment: It's not a total order. Some natural numbers do not have a unique representation as a sum of two squares. For example $50 = 1^{2} + 7^{2} = 5^{2} + 5^{2}$. $(1,7)\sigma (5,5)$ or $(5,5)\sigma (1,7)$ does not occur. Therefore, the connectedness condition is not satisfied.

Comment: if i say that it is not a total order, is it true so that all other 4 statements are useless?

Comment: They only really relate to it if every element is comparable. But we shown its not. I'm not sure on your own use on those statements, but they are kinda useless.